# How to multiple table joins in GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm a newbie for GOlang and GORM, I have some confusion how to multiple table join using GORM.

Example:

Tables:

```
Department - Fields (gorm.Modal, dep_name)
Employee - Fields (gorm.Modal, emp_id, emp_name, department_id) //employee is department table child 
EmployeeContact - Fields (gorm.Modal, employee_id, emp_contact_no)//Employee contact table is employee table child
```

Query

```
SELECT * FROM department d, employee e, employeeContact ec WHERE d.id = e.department_id and e.id = ec.employee_id
```

How to make the above query using GORM?

Comment: db.Joins() can be used for performing joins in gorm. Check if it solves your problem.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, But how can I used multiple tables? @AnkitDeshpande

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for the solution here but since I already figured it out by myself, I would like to post it here also. My query was a bit different and I was joining only 2 tables but I think this one should work, too.

```
if err := db.Table("employee").Select("department.id, employee.department_id, employeeContact.employee_id").Joins("JOIN department on department.id = employee.department_id").Joins("JOIN employeeContact on employeeContact.id = employee.id").Find(&results).Error; err != nil {
    return err, ""
}
```

Comment: Can't we use PreLoad()?

Comment: Preload does not complete the execution with one database query though.  It hits the database serially to retrieve associated records.

Comment: @kiranmalvi Do not use Preload since it retrieves records N+1 using "IN" clause. Meaning, "IN" clause will grow if records in your origin table grow. Preload is a terrible idea for tables with a lot of records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Preload` **but notice that the Preload didn't optimize for this query**

First, suppose have been defined models:

```
type Department struct{
    gorm.Modal
    DepName string
    Employees *[]Employee
}

type Employee struct{
    gorm.Modal
    EmpId int
    EmpName string
    DepartmentId int
    Department Department
}

type EmployeeContact struct{
    gorm.Modal
    EmpId int
    EmpContactNo string
}
```

Then we can use this example for multiple joins:

```
var department Department
db.
Model(&Department{}).
Where("DepName = ?", form.DepName).
Preload("Employees", func(tx *gorm.DB) *gorm.DB {
    return tx.Preload("Department")
}).Find(&department)
```