# Filter db rows with GORM preload

Tags: database, go, orm, go-gorm

Currently, I got this struct

```
type Token struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name             string `gorm:"column:name"`
    Enabled          bool   `gorm:"column:enabled"`
    Symbol           string `gorm:"column:symbol"`
    TokenDetails    []*EarnTokenDetail   `gorm:"foreignkey:TokenID;references:ID"`
}

type EarnTokenDetail struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name               string     `gorm:"column:name"`
    TokenID            uint64     `gorm:"column:token_id"`
    Enabled          bool   `gorm:"column:enabled"`
    Chains             *EarnChain `gorm:"foreignkey:ID;references:ChainID"`
}

type EarnChain struct {
    ID        uint64    `gorm:"primary_key column:id"`
    Enabled          bool   `gorm:"column:enabled"`
    Name      string    `gorm:"column:name"`
}
```

And this GORM query:

```
    var tokens []*model.Token
    result := e.db.
        WithContext(ctx).
        Preload("TokenDetails", "token_details.enabled = true").
        Preload("TokenDetails.Chains", "chains.enabled = true").
        Find(&tokens, "tokens.enabled = true")
```

It works fine when everything is enabled, but when I disable chains in the database, the result will still show the tokens with disabled chains, with the `Chains` field empty.

How can I filter out those rows while still using preload?

Answer (score 1):

According the the GORM documentation, that's the expected behavior. It does one query after another, so there is no way to "drop" results of the former queries. If you don't want these results at all - not even with an empty `Chain` field, consider to use `Join()` to filter out those. I think I even found a comment pointing that out: [How to multiple table joins in GORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244274/how-to-multiple-table-joins-in-gorm#comment123086923_52949659)